# output values from hash using values from another hash perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have two hash:

```
my %hash1 = {
   "GOKIN_0_1" => "alpha",
   "GOKIN_4_6" => "omega",
   ....
}

my %hash2 = {
   "alpha" => "aaa",
   "omega" => "bbb",
   ...
```

}

What I want to do is, to print in a file lines a value of hash1 that match key of hash2 to have a file like that:

```
GOKIN_0_1    aaa  
GOKIN_4_6    bbb
....
```

Here is part my code to do that:

```
 my $v1 = values %hash1;

 for my $k1 (keys(%hash1)) {
     print OUT "$v1\t$hash2{$k1}\n";
 }
```

Thanks you so much.

Comment: Please read up on [mcve]. The code you posted has made the answerers waste effort. If you post code which can not be compiled/interpreted, then explicitly state so. This is however only adequate when your question is explicitly on the reason for being non-interpretable. For your question, your code should be runnable, even if it only almost does what you want. `use strict; use warnings;`.

Answer (score 2):

First, hashes are declared with `()`, not `{}`. The latter denotes a hash *reference*.

Now, what you can do is loop over the keys and values of `%hash1`, check if the value is in `%hash2` as a key, then print the required variables if the value does exist as a key:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash1 = (
   "GOKIN_0_1" => "alpha",
   "GOKIN_4_6" => "omega",
   "GOKIN_4_9" => "blah",
);

my %hash2 = (
   "alpha" => "aaa",
   "omega" => "bbb",
);

while (my ($k, $v) = each %hash1){
    if (exists $hash2{$v}){
        print "$k\t$hash2{$v}\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
GOKIN_4_6   bbb
GOKIN_0_1   aaa
```

Comment: producing output that depends on hash ordering is almost never the right thing.  How about a version that sorts?

Answer (score 0):

So first off, your two hashes are declared incorrectly. You've got braces where you want regular brackets. Turning on warnings with `use warnings;` should highlight that mistake.

```
my %hash1 = (
   "GOKIN_0_1" => "alpha",
   "GOKIN_4_6" => "omega",
   );

my %hash2 = (
   "alpha" => "aaa",
   "omega" => "bbb",
   );
```

Once you've got two hashes you can use the value from one - `$hash1{$k1}` - as the key to the second one like this to link the key `$k1` to the second hashes value.

```
for my $k1 (keys(%hash1)) {
  print OUT "$k1\t$hash2{$hash1{$k1}}\n";
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to use the value from `%hash1` to check if it's a key in `%hash2`, and only print if that condition is met. You missed the filtering part.

Comment: @stevieb the requirement for filtering is just one way of reading the question.  The other is that there will always be a match

Comment: @ysth The question is a bit ambiguous in a couple of ways :)

Comment: Given their example code doesn't do filtering and their data has no non-matches, it's hard to say for certain if filtering is an actual requirement or not

Comment: producing output that depends on hash ordering is almost never the right thing. How about a version that sorts?

Comment: @ysth feel free to throw in your own answer if you think you know what the OP actually wants, but there is nothing in the question about having the output sorted